# ¿Método para realizar copia de una matriz multidimensional? (Mejor que usando un recorrido recursivo)

Tags: javascript

Como sabrán, en javascript cuando a una variable se le asigna otra (`a=b`), en caso de que la origen contenga un objeto no se le realiza una copia, si no una referencia (un puntero), de manera que modificando el valor queda reflejado en las dos.
Por ejemplo:

```js
var matriz = ["a1","a2"];
var copiaMatriz = matriz;
matriz[0]="x";
copiaMatriz[1]="y";
console.log(matriz,copiaMatriz);
```

El sistema que uso actualmente para solucionar este problema, es recorriendo la matriz *recursivamente* y asignando los valores a medida que no son otras matrices ( si los valores son otro tipo de objetos que no sean `Array` (por ejemplo funciones), seguirán siendo referencias, cosa que no me supone ningún problema).
Ejemplo con una matriz de 3 dimensiones:

```js
var matriz =["a0" , "a1" , [
    "b0", "b1", [
      "c0", "c1"]
  ]
];

function copiaMatriz(matriz){
  var copia=[];
  matriz.forEach(function(valor){
        if (Array.isArray(valor)) copia.push(copiaMatriz(valor));
        else copia.push(valor);
    });
    return copia;
};

var matrizCopia = copiaMatriz(matriz);

matriz[2][2][0]="X";
matrizCopia[2][2][1]="Y";

console.log(matriz[2][2][0],matriz[2][2][1]);
console.log(matrizCopia[2][2][0],matrizCopia[2][2][1]);
```

Me extraña bastante que en JavaScript el objeto `Array` no tenga ya un método para realizar una copia de la matriz, u otro sistema más rápido, tengo la sensación que debe ser mas sencillo y que me estoy complicando la vida.
**Mi pregunta es:** ¿Existe algún método para realizar una copia de una matriz *multidimensional* que sea mas rápido que mi función actual? (o sea, que corra un nivel por debajo usando algún método del objeto `Array` o "truco" que desconozca).
Pd. Evidentemente busco un sistema que funcione en cualquier matriz de cualquier dimensión.

**EDIT**
He encontrado que usando métodos del objeto `JSON` pueden realizar una copia de un array multidimensional, pero haciendo pruebas resulta ser casi igual o mas lento que la copia recursiva. (Depende del navegador y el estado de la caché, a veces resulta más rápido, pero poco.)
Ejemplo copiando 10 veces una matriz 100x100x100.

```js
var valores=100; // Array de valores x valores x valores
    var matriz =[];
    for (let i=0; i<valores; i++){
        matriz[i]=[];
        for (let j=0; j<valores; j++){
            matriz[i][j]=[];
            for (k=0; k<valores; k++){
                matriz[i][j][k]=Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
            }
        }
    }

    var copias=10;

    var matrizCopia=[];
    
    var inicio=Date.now();
    for (i=0; i<copias; i++){
        matrizCopia=copiaMatriz(matriz);
    }
    console.log("Funcion matrizCopiar: "+(Date.now()-inicio)+"ms.");

    var matrizCopia2=[];
    
    var inicio=Date.now();
    for (i=0; i<copias; i++){
        matrizCopia2=copiaMatriz2(matriz);
    }
    console.log("Funcion matrizCopiar2: "+(Date.now()-inicio)+"ms.");
    
    console.log("Comprobando que realiza copias y no referencias");
    matriz[0][0][0]="a";
    matrizCopia[0][0][1]="b";
    matrizCopia2[0][0][2]="c";
    console.log(matriz[0][0][0],matrizCopia[0][0][0],matrizCopia2[0][0][0]);
    console.log(matriz[0][0][1],matrizCopia[0][0][1],matrizCopia2[0][0][1]);
    console.log(matriz[0][0][2],matrizCopia[0][0][2],matrizCopia2[0][0][2]);

    
    function copiaMatriz(matriz){
        var copia=[];
        matriz.forEach(function(valor){
            if (Array.isArray(valor)) copia.push(copiaMatriz(valor));
            else copia.push(valor);
        });
        return copia;
    };
    
    function copiaMatriz2(matriz){
        return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(matriz));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, no hay un metodo por defecto para hacer en eso en el core. Te recomendaría usar la librería Lodash https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep. Tiene un metodo `cloneDeep` que hace "deep cloning" muy bien optimizado y que te permite personalizar con un callback. La firma es `_.cloneDeepWith(value, [customizer])`.