# Cómo actualizar una propiedad en un array de objetos clonado, sin afectar el original

Tags: javascript

Al clonar un array de objetos y actualizar una de sus propiedades, el array original también se actualiza. ¿Cómo hago para evitar este comportamiento?. Gracias. Este es mi código:

```
test1 = [
        {
            'prop1': 'prop1',
            'prop2': 'prop2'
        },
        {
            'prop1': '45',
            'prop2': '60'
        }
    ];

test2 = [...test1];

test2[1].prop2 = '800'
```

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/380530/m%c3%a9todo-para-realizar-copia-de-una-matriz-multidimensional-mejor-que-usando-un

Comment: No hay una manera estandar de hacerlo como bien menciona @ArnauCastellví pero si es posible haciendole una jugada en el código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para un objeto sencillo, puedes usar `.map()`, desesctructurando cada elemento del arreglo.

```js
test1 = [
        {
            'prop1': 'prop1',
            'prop2': 'prop2'
        },
        {
            'prop1': '45',
            'prop2': '60'
        }
    ];

test2 = test1.map(item => { return {...item}; });

test2[1].prop2 = '800';

console.log(test1, test2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Como mencionaba en el comentario no hay una manera estandar, así que dejo un aporte de como podrías hacerlo

```js
const test1 = [{
    'prop1': 'prop1',
    'prop2': 'prop2'
  },
  {
    'prop1': '45',
    'prop2': '60'
  }
];

// Convertimos el arreglo en string
const str = JSON.stringify(test1);
// Parseamos el string a un arreglo
const test2 = JSON.parse(str);

test2[1].prop2 = '800';

// Imprimimos ambos arreglos
console.log(test2, test1);
```

Espero te sirva, Saludos.